# Why computed property works on preserving the reactivity but attributes in data() {} does not

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_conditional_rendering), where they point out a small bug with the checkbox status of forgetting the state of the ticked/unticked which can be solved by using the computed property.

I would like to ask, even if the attribute `isDone` in Data (`ToDoItem.vue`) has been changed to `true` (by ticking the checkbox), why the box is still `unticked` after clicking edit then cancel, and why computed property could solve this bug.

Below are parts of the scripts.

**ToDoItem.vue**

```
    <template>
  <div class="stack-small" v-if="!isEditing">
    <div class="custom-checkbox">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        class="checkbox"
        :id="id"
        :checked="isDone"
        @change="$emit('checkbox-changed')"
      />
      <label :for="id" class="checkbox-label">{{ label }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn"
        ref="editButton"
        @click="toggleToItemEditForm"
      >
        Edit <span class="visually-hidden">{{ label }}</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn__danger" @click="deleteToDo">
        Delete <span class="visually-hidden">{{ label }}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <to-do-item-edit-form
    v-else
    :id="id"
    :label="label"
    @item-edited="itemEdited"
    @edit-cancelled="editCancelled"
  ></to-do-item-edit-form>
</template>

<script>
import ToDoItemEditForm from "./ToDoItemEditForm";

export default {
  components: {
    ToDoItemEditForm,
  },

  props: {
    label: { required: true, type: String },
    done: { default: false, type: Boolean },
    id: { required: true, type: String },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isEditing: false,
      isDone: this.done, // after deleting this line and use 
                         //computed: {} below, the bug is solved.
    };
  },
  
  // computed: {
  //   isDone() {
  //     return this.done;
  //   },
  // },
};
</script>
```

**ToDoItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    <to-do-form @todo-added="addToDo"></to-do-form>
    <h2 id="list-summary" ref="listSummary" tabindex="-1"> {{ listSummary }} </h2>
    <ul aria-labelledby="list-summary" class="stack-large">
      <li v-for="item in ToDoItems" :key="item.id">
        <to-do-item
          :label="item.label"
          :done="item.done"
          :id="item.id"
          @checkbox-changed="updateDoneStatus(item.id)"
          @item-deleted="deleteToDo(item.id)"
          @item-edited="editToDo(item.id, $event)"
        >
        </to-do-item>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

 <script>
 import ToDoItem from "./components/ToDoItem.vue";
 import ToDoForm from "./components/ToDoForm.vue";
 import uniqueId from "lodash.uniqueid";

 export default {
    name: "app",
    components: {
    ToDoItem,
    ToDoForm,
    },

  data() {
    return {
      ToDoItems: [],
    };
  },

methods: {
  updateDoneStatus(toDoId) {
    const toDoToUpdate = this.ToDoItems.find((item) => item.id === toDoId);
    toDoToUpdate.done = !toDoToUpdate.done;
    console.dir(toDoToUpdate.done)
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in vue, but I believe that the `this.done` being assigned to `isDone:` is only done once in `data()`, and it wouldn't be done if the props change (the value of `isDone` in `data()` won't change when the prop `done` changes). While in computed, `isDone` will watch the `done` prop value, and if that prop value changes, the computed will be notified and thus changes the `isDone` data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it makes great sense to me! Can I ask further what's the advantage of using computed compared with passing `this.done` into `:checked` (`:checked="done"`) in this case? Both ways work fine on my end.

Comment: @TYzzz I think in this case, passing `done` directly wouldn't be a problem since you are not directly editing the props from inside the component (it's updated via `$emit('checkbox-changed')`), and when `done` is updated, the render will be notified. Also please accept/vote the answer if it did answer your question